# CouchDB POST request using curl hanging

Tags: curl, post, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have CouchDB v2.2.0 installed on a Linux server.
I have 5 databases create:

- das
- model_attribute_groups
- mydemo
- registry
- verifytestdb

I can successfully run a Mango query from Fauxton using the contents of the json file listed below.

I can successfully connect to the model_attriubute_groups database from another Linux server using a curl GET command:

curl -v http://my.server.com:5984/model_attribute_groups/_all_docs

I am trying to compose the curl command to run the JSON Mango query from the other Linux Server.

I have my Mango Query in a file: "mangoReqPay" which ls -l tells me is 221 characters long.

```
{  "selector": {"status":"stable", "model":"PC-20",  "variant":{    "$in": ["15",  "30"]    }  },  "fields":["_id","_rev","status",  "model","variant","variant-type",  "oem","historicaloem","displaymodel",  "sactmodel"]}
```

Here is the command that I am trying to use.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Length: 221" \
 -X POST \
 -d mangoReqPay \
 -H "Host: http://my.server.com:5984/model_attribute_groups\_find"
```

When I submit this command, I get no response, it just sits there appearing to wait for more input.

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified a URL. Your host name in "-H" parameter is NOT the url you want curl to request - it just sets the header.

When I run the command I get the error (and rightly so):

```
curl: no URL specified!
```

Just specify the URL you want curl to fetch without any flags at the end (or at the beginning).

Also you do not need "Content-Length: 221". If you want it to read from a file you start the filename with '@'

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, especially the part about prefixing the input file with '@'.  That combined with a couple of tweaks of the URL and the addition of -u <username> got me to success.  Here is the working version of the curl command.

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST -d @mangoReqPay \
-u myUserId \
http://my.server.boeing.com:5984/model_attribute_groups/_find`

Now, onto understanding "rewrites"!